# Typescript: How to extract types of an object keys

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I'm trying to use an object as holder for various possible colors as below.

```
  const cardColors = {
    primaryGradientColor: "",
    secondaryGradientColor: "",
    titleTextColor: "",
    borderColor: "",
    categoryTextColor: "",
  };
```

Now I want to update these items individually using a function.

```
  const updateColor = (colorType: typeof cardColors, color: string) => {
    cardColors[colorType] = color;
  }
```

But I face this error

```
Type '{ primaryGradientColor: string; secondaryGradientColor: string; titleTextColor: string; borderColor: string; categoryTextColor: string; }' cannot be used as an index type.
```

I'm expecting to use the object as source of types for the function parameter as shown above.

I don't want to create separate type of this object as I will have to update it in atleast two places which is unnecessary, but I want to use this object as source of verification of types.

Also, I'm new to typescript.

Comment: `const updateColor = (colorType: keyof typeof cardColors, color: string)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below.

```
 type cardColorType = "primaryGradientColor" | "secondaryGradientColor" | "titleTextColor" | "borderColor" | "categoryTextColor";

 let cardColors = Record<cardColorType, string>;

 const updateColor = (colorType: cardColorType, color: string) => {
   cardColors = {
     ...cardColors,
     [colorType]: color
   }
 }
```

Also I think you should use useState for cardColors.

```
 type cardColorType = "primaryGradientColor" | "secondaryGradientColor" | "titleTextColor" | "borderColor" | "categoryTextColor";

 const [cardColors, setCardColors] = useState<Record<cardColorType, string>>({});

 const updateColor = useCallback((colorType: cardColorType, color: string) => {
   setCardColors({
     ...cardColors,
     [colorType]: color
   });
 }, [cardColors, setCardColors]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use keyof to achieve what you want. like this:

```js
const cardColors = {
  primaryGradientColor: "",
  secondaryGradientColor: "",
  titleTextColor: "",
  borderColor: "",
  categoryTextColor: "",
};

const updateColor = (colorType: keyof typeof cardColors, color: string) => {
  cardColors[colorType] = color;
}
```